# React: component's render() is NOT invoked after this.setState() is called

Tags: reactjs

My component's `render()` method is NOT called after a change of state with `this.setState()`.

This is the method where the component's state is changed (it is invoked and I have verified this):

```
  handlePhoneNumberChange = name => (event) => {
    const { contactPhone } = this.state;

    const index = name;
    const phoneEntry = contactPhone[index];
    phoneEntry.phoneNumber = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ contactPhone });
  };
```

This is the component's initial state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      contactPhone: [{ phoneNumber: '', phoneType: '' }],
    };
  }
```

This is how the TextField is rendered:

```
{contactPhone.map((phone, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
                <TextField
                  id={String(Math.random())}
                  label="Phone number"
                  type="tel"
                  value={phone.phoneNumber}
                  onChange={this.handlePhoneNumberChange(index)}
                  placeholder="Contact phone number"
                  margin="normal"
                />
                <br />
    </div>
))}
```

Why isn't render being invoked after setState()?

Comment: try `onChange={this.handlePhoneNumberChange.bind(index, this)}` this and check.

Comment: I'm using ES6 hash rocket notation so I don't see how that could be the issue

Comment: What is `TextField`. Can you show the component? Maybe the prop `onChange` is not attached to the DOM node?

Comment: https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/. handlePhoneNumberChange is invoked so I don't think there's a problem there.

Comment: i think reference of `contactPhone` isn't changing that's why react won't be able to understand that contactPhone is changed.

Comment: Isn't setState supposed to invoke render() no matter what?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/z6lplw9z74  see this is your code and in pre and post contactPhone values are same and changed.

Comment: From React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):
_Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately._
You are not actually changing the state so no render is called. You are mutating `phoneEntry` but no changes are made to `contactPhone`.

Comment: @bamse This is incorrect. phoneEntry is just a reference to an element inside contactPhone array (it is not a copy of that element). contactPhone is indeed being modified

Comment: You are right!
This is your problem. 
From docs: _Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable._

Comment: @bamse I think you might be right, can you please write up an answer explaining further and also with a fix code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `handlePhoneNumberChange` function mutates state directly. The React [docs states](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state): *Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.*

The simplest fix is to *clone* contactPhone, change it and pass it to state

```
handlePhoneNumberChange = index => (event) => {
  const contactPhone = [...this.state.contactPhone]; // at this point contactPhone !== this.state.contactPhone
  const phoneEntry = contactPhone[index];
  phoneEntry.phoneNumber = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ contactPhone });
};
```

Should work!

---

```
const cloneArray = [...someArray]; // spread syntax
```

is the same as

```
const cloneArray = someArray.slice(0);
```

Both produce an array that contains the same values as `someArray` but are not the same array.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to write "de-structuring syntax"? This is a different concept than what you're showing. Perhaps you meant to say "spread syntax"?

Comment: Right! I'll adjust the answer. 
I wanted to be clear what is happening there but got the word wrong. Thanks!

Comment: While your solution is correct - I'm still trying to get clarity on why render() is NOT called after setState. The state indeed changes even if you don't make a copy of the contactPhone array. I have verified this by calling render() manually and have verified that the state changes by logging it there. This is still an enigma to me. Very weird. This must be something internal to React.js that isn't properly documented or explained anywhere.

Comment: Please take a look at [this example](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#examples). I don't think you are using `React.PureComponent` but the example and the [power of not mutating data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) might shed more light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is a terrible idea to assign the list key to a random stringified number, `key={String(Math.random())}`, because the key will change with each render call and React will not be able to reconcile the virtual DOM properly when `this.setState` is invoked. React keeps track of which list items have changed by diff-ing list items with the same key.

See link below for further details on React reconcilation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Comment: What does this have to do with my question?

Comment: It has everything to do with your question. Assuming there isn't something else wrong in your code, since there is a lot missing that I have to assume "works". React will not know what has changed if the key of the input changes from one state to next.

Comment: But why isn't render() being called?

Comment: Can you verify that your `handlePhoneNumberChange` is being invoked by writing in a console.log inside of it. If you put your code on [CodeSandbox](www.codesandox.com), I can take a look at it in more detail.

Comment: You contactPhone array is never changing. You just destructure it from the current state and then put it back in without any changes.

Comment: Why? phoneEntry is just a reference to an element inside array contactPhone. – etayluz 3 mins ago    edit

Comment: Sure ... but `const phoneEntry = contactPhone[index];` that does not change the property with the same name found in `this.state.contactPhone`.

Comment: What property? There is no such property.

Comment: Just check ... `console.log(this.state.contactPhone)` before and after the call to setState ... it will be the same.

Comment: I did - it changes

Comment: then humor me and change the key to simply be the index

Comment: I did - makes no difference

Comment: Could I get a screenshot of this output to help debug?

Comment: Could I at least get my -1 removed from my answer, since I'm positive your component would not render properly if the key kept changing.

Comment: I can't undo it but you can just delete your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need revisit your `handlePhoneNumberChange` function: 
You here not making changes, you setting same value twice.
Reference for `Array` `contactPhone` is same

```
handlePhoneNumberChange = name => (event) => {
    // its destructed, but not changed later
    const { contactPhone } = this.state;
    //  no changes
    const index = name;
    const phoneEntry = contactPhone[index];
    phoneEntry.phoneNumber = event.target.value;

    // you set same value, nothing changed
    this.setState({ contactPhone });
  };
```

Comment: Why am I not making changes? `phoneEntry` is just a reference to an element inside array `contactPhone`.

Comment: please add to comment what is your goal here, because here is nothing changed. `contactPhone` is the same `Array` after `setState` like before `setState`

Comment: No it's not. Please read the code. And what if it is the same?

Comment: if the same, the component not re-rerenders

Comment: Why not? I don't agree

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifying the state here. You are setting it to the same value you had initially.
Update the code as below.

```
handlePhoneNumberChange = name => (event) => {
    const { contactPhone } = this.state;
    const index = name;
    const phoneEntry = contactPhone[index];
    phoneEntry.phoneNumber = event.target.value;
    contactPhone = [...contactPhone,phoneEntry]
    this.setState({ contactPhone });
};
```

Comment: This would just add a new element to the contactPhone array, why would I do that?

Comment: If you aren't changing the state, why would you want to trigger the render() ?
If you want to force the render method however, perhaps try changing the state by using contactPhone = [...contactPhone] and then setState ?

Comment: I am changing the state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it works but it solves it:

I changed:

```
this.setState({ contactPhone });
```

To:

```
this.setState({ contactPhone: [...contactPhone] });
```

`[...contactPhone]` simply creates a new object. But now the render() is being called. Very weird.

Comment: thats work because is not the same `Array`, like i pointed in my comment or in my answer...

Comment: You answer is that contactPhone array does NOT change. And it does. I don't know why this works.

Comment: i have already commented `i think reference of contactPhone isn't changing that's why react won't be able to understand that contactPhone is changed.`

Comment: I have logged contactPhone before and after. It is changing. I still don't know why this works.

Comment: @etayluz yes it's changing you are right!!! but reference doesn't that's why react setstate doesn't understand that variable is changed and that's why it's not calling render function again.

Comment: `this.setState({ contactPhone: [...contactPhone] });` by doing this new object get's created with same value but reference is changed so that react knows that i need to change this variable and it will calls render method.

Comment: Where does it say that the reference needs to change for that to happen?